# Correct endpoints for requesting basic account info for Microsoft accounts

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to implement a very simple 'Sign in with Microsoft' button for my website. I already have a correctly-functioning Google button and want to mimic that behaviour. Simply, it should sign the user in to Microsoft (using a managed Microsoft account of the sort that are issued by schools with Office 365), then provide my app with email address and name.

However, I'm struggling to find the correct endpoint to return the basic user info after sign-in.

I have successfully requested authorisation codes from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=...` and returned these to my app. I have also been able to then successfully use `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=...` to return the desired data. However, this only works for personal Live accounts, not for professional Office 365 accounts.

Basically, does anybody know the correct endpoint I can send the authorisation code to that will return the email address and name attached to an Office 365 account? I have tried `https://login.windows.net/common/openid/userinfo`, using the curl request below, but only receive a '1' in response.

```
$url = "https://login.windows.net/common/openid/userinfo" ;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorisation: Bearer $access_token"));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

Comment: Did you mean want to get user list? or specific user info? You can get `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`  [User List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}`  [Specific user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: You could refer this docs for [php example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial#exchanging-the-code-for-a-token)

Comment: @md I want, at minimum, their email address, but ideally also their name. How could I use the second one without knowing their id or user name? All I have is the token from their sign in

Comment: I understand In that case you can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. what all you need to do is pass the token you receive against logged in user.. If you need I can add C# example for you as I am not very familiar with php.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you. I think I've cracked it. The main issue (as well as some silly typos) was that I was attempting to target the endpoint using the ```id_token``` rather than the ```access_token```. I followed the article here with success: https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/

Comment: So your problem resolved? Let me know if you have any more concern.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes, thank you for all your help

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Sure, thanks. May also be useful to add a link to the article in my comment above, as tbh it was much more useful than most of the official documentation

Comment: I have updated the answer please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get user information in following endpoint:

**User List:**

For getting User List the valid endpoint is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

**Individual User :**

For getting individual user the valid endpoint is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

**Sign In  User :**

For getting sign in user the valid endpoint is:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Permission Required:**

To do this request you need following permission in azure portal

[image]

**Further Reference:**

For more details help you could refer below docs

1. [Php code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial#exchanging-the-code-for-a-token)
2. [Azure Active Directory V2.0 Endpoint](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/)